# Saving all lines in a file after a certain string to a separate file

Tags: python

I have a file containing a block of introductory text for an unknown number of lines, then the rest of the file contains data. Before the data block begins, there are column titles and I want to skip those also. So the file looks something like this:

```
this is an introduction..
blah blah blah...
...
UniqueString
Time Position Count
0 35 12
1 48 6
2 96 8
...
1000 82 37
```

I want to record the Time Position and Count data to a separate file. Time Position and Count Data appears only after `UniqueString`.

Comment: I would recommend using a CSV reader (since your file after the header line is formatted as a table) with a `while` loop that skips the lines until it finds the headers.

Comment: Also, please consider that the data could easily have 1e8 to 1e9 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you're looking for?

```
reduce(lambda x, line: (x and (outfile.write(line) or x)) or line=='UniqueString\n', infile)
```

How it works:

- files can be iterated, so we can read `infile` line by line by simply doing `[... for line in infile]`
- in the operation part, we use the fact that `writeline()` will not be triggered if the first operand for and is `False`.
- in the `or` part, we set up the trigger if the desired line is found, so `writeline` will be fired for the next and consequent lines
- default initial value for reduce is None, which evaluates to `False`

Comment: I have tried this (copied it directly and just changed variable names), but it only records the second line in the block of introductory text.

Comment: missed one condition (`(outfile.write(line) or x)`). Please try again

Answer (score 0):

You could extract and write the data to another file like this:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as infile:
    x = infile.readlines()

x = [i.strip() for i in x[x.index('UniqueString\n') + 1:] if i != '\n' ]

with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for i in x[1:]:
        outfile.write(i+"\n")
```

It is pretty straight forward I think: The file is opened and all lines are read, a list comprehension slices the list beginning with the header string and the desired remaining lines are wrote to file again.

Comment: `readlines()` and subsequent `"\n".join` are not memory efficient. I.e. it will cause problems if infile is sufficiently big

Comment: How big are we talking?

Comment: Data can easily contain 100 million to 1 billion rows. Also, the actual data files I'm working with have 12 columns

Comment: Updated it. Does this do what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [***generator function***](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators) (and more info [***here***](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.3.html#pep-255-simple-generators)) that filtered the file for you. 
It operates incrementally so doesn't require reading the entire file into memory at one time.

```
def extract_lines_following(file, marker=None):
    """Generator yielding all lines in file following the line following the marker.
    """
    marker_seen = False
    while True:
        line = file.next()
        if marker_seen:
            yield line
        elif line.strip() == marker:
            marker_seen = True
            file.next()  # skip following line, too

# sample usage
with open('test_data.txt', 'r') as infile, open('cleaned_data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(extract_lines_following(infile, 'UniqueString'))
```

This could be optimized a little if you're using Python 3, but the basic idea would be the same.